# $http.post strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component which I used to post to the `Rest API` engine.
The component looks like:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('ComponentRelease', ['ServiceRelease'])
        .component('createRelease', {
            templateUrl: 'components/release/createRelease.html',
            controller: CreateRelease,
            controllerAs: 'clCtrl',
        })

    function CreateRelease($http, getReleaseManagers, insertRelease) {
        var ctrl = this;

        this.$onInit = function() {
            getReleaseManagers.promise($http).then(function(response) {
                ctrl.managers = response.data.releasemanager;
            });

            //the save button
            ctrl.save = function() {
                var release = { "rName": ctrl.r_name, "releaseDate": ctrl.r_date, "releaseSharepoint": ctrl.r_sharepoint, "gManager": ctrl.gname, "pManager": ctrl.pname };

                $http.post('http://localhost:8080/post', release).then(function(response) {
                    console.log("Save in database");
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e);

                });
            };
        };
    };
})(window.angular);
```

If the save is ok in the console log I see undefined if i have errors is showing the error message. Maybe i did not understand correct, but if the post is ok i should see the message Save in Database. 
Please can you help me understand why this situation?
I am using `angularjs 1.6`

Thank you in advance for your help,
Eugen

Comment: what does the server return in case of "successful" save?

Comment: it was a problem on the server side. the server was sending a string as response but it should be a json object.

Answer (score 0):

In your angular post, you should also send header content-type in configuration for server to parse data type correctly (application/json).

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ComponentRelease', ['ServiceRelease'])
    .component('createRelease', {
      templateUrl: 'components/release/createRelease.html',
      controller: CreateRelease,
      controllerAs: 'clCtrl',
    })

  function CreateRelease($http, getReleaseManagers, insertRelease) {
    var ctrl = this;

    this.$onInit = function() {
      getReleaseManagers.promise($http).then(function(response) {
        ctrl.managers = response.data.releasemanager;
      });

      //the save button
      ctrl.save = function() {
        var release = {
          "rName": ctrl.r_name,
          "releaseDate": ctrl.r_date,
          "releaseSharepoint": ctrl.r_sharepoint,
          "gManager": ctrl.gname,
          "pManager": ctrl.pname
        };

        var config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/post', release, config).then(function(response) {
          console.log("Save in database");
        }, function(e) {
          console.log(e);

        });
      };
    };
  };
})(window.angular);
```